# Dual functional integrated Digital Cathode Ray Oscilloscope and Digital Multimeter product

Tags: signal-analysis, digital

Is it feasible to design & construct a Dual functional integrated Digital Cathode Ray Oscilloscope and Digital Multimeter products in a single product?

Idea is to integrate the Digital Multimeter features in the Digital Cathode Ray Oscilloscope Device.

i.e. Re-engineering the Digital CRO product to add the Digital Multimeter features and Functions.

The CRO should work with both Primary mains AC supply and DC Batteries. A mode (CRO + Multimeter) button to toggle the waveforms display on the CRO display panel and the electronic components reading on the CRO display panel.

If No, What are the Technical limitations to achieve this?

[image][image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Off course you can and many scopes already integrate some Multi-meter functionality in their software.

Conceptually you can just glue a multi-meter to the side of the scope and you have the product you asked for, although industrial design probably wouldn't like it!

Starting from there you can integrate more: power supply, display, inputs etc.

Most tricky part will be the inputs. Scope inputs are designed for speed and low noise, MM inputs are designed for high voltage, high current and low cost, so you will likely end up with some extra connectors (at least for current and impedance measurements).

Comment: Fluke has some multimeters with some oscilloscope/data logging capabilities. Luke the Fluke 435, 438, 1750

Comment: Obviously I meant Like not Luke ;)